# javascript two color repeating effect

Tags: javascript, css, colors, effect, repeat

Is there a way to repeat two colors one ofther another with javascript.. For example I have some text in 3 different boxes.

1. Text 1
2. Text 2
3. Text 3

Now I want the 1 and 3 to be with red and the second to be black.. now every time I add some new line, the colors to change, if I add Text 4 - to be - black, then Text 5 - red.

Is there a way to do this only with js ?

Comment: For future reference, it's called zebra striping

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with jQuery's [odd selector](http://api.jquery.com/odd-selector/) or [even selector](http://api.jquery.com/even-selector/) its 0-based so:

> In particular, note that the 0-based
>   indexing means that,
>   counter-intuitively, :odd selects the
>   second element, fourth element, and so
>   on within the matched set.

let's say you have these li elements:

```
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
</ul>
```

and the following css:

```
.red{
    color: red;
}

.green{
    color: green;
}
```

and if you use jQuery and do this get the element and attach class name for the appropriate color scheme for odd or even:

```
console.log($('li:odd'));  //[<li>​2​</li>​, <li>​4​</li>​] you'll get these elements
console.log($('li:even')); //[<li>​1​</li>​,<li>​3​</li>​,<li>​5​</li>​] you'll get these
$('li:odd').addClass(' red'); // turn color to red
$('li:even').addClass(' green'); //turn color to green
```

**or in regular JavaScript:**

```
var myLi = document.getElementsByTagName('li');

for(var i=0; i<myLi.length; i++){
    if(i%2 == 0)
        myLi[i].className += ' red';
    else
        myLi[i].className += ' green';
}
```

Comment: First, the OP said red and black. Second, you don't need a space before the class names if you're using jQuery's `.addClass()` method.

Comment: thanks for the clarification. OP please use whatever color you desire =)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [jQuery](http://jquery.com) to do that, but if you're a beginner, it's better to learn some vanilla JS first.

```
function isOdd(num) {
    return num % 2;
}

var para = document.getElementById('container').getElementsByTagName('p');

for (var i = 0; i < para.length; i++) {
    // for readability
    para[i].style.color = 'white';

    if (isOdd(i)) {
        para[i].style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    } else {
        para[i].style.backgroundColor = 'black';
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Nyuszika7H/8h7RZ/1/embedded/result%2Cjs%2Chtml/

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul id="mylist">
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
<li>4</li>
<li>5</li>
</ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
  liArray=document.getElementById('mylist');
  for(l=0;l<liArray.length;l++){
    if(l%2==1){
      liArray[l].style.color='#ff0000';
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: It's `liArray=document.getElementById('mylist').children;` and `liArray.length` should be stored.

Comment: No didn't work..

It's little confusing.. the outputed text is based on php .. he send that to a template, then the template output's the php variables.

I have only 1 div and inside of it the php variables.

Comment: @waraza as per @DanMan this answer is not correct.  use `var liArray=document.getElementById('mylist').children;` if you are to use this answer